# An issue with GoRouter initialization

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Below is my code for `GoRouter` and `authController`, along with the logs.
When the `login` method is called, `GoRouter` initializes and returns to the splash screen.
I understand that when the `login` method is called, the `loginStatus` in `authController` changes to `loading`, which then triggers the `redirect` in `GoRouter`.
However, I don't understand why it initializes again.
Can anyone explain the reason for this?

- code

```
// router
final routeProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final authController = ref.watch(authControllerProvider);
  return GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: '/${AppRoute.splash.name}',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/${AppRoute.splash.name}',
        name: AppRoute.splash.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/${AppRoute.login.name}',
        name: AppRoute.login.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/${AppRoute.nickname.name}',
        name: AppRoute.nickname.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const NicknameScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/${AppRoute.home.name}',
        name: AppRoute.home.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    ],
    redirect: (context, state) {
      final isLoggedIn = authController.isLoggedIn;
      final isNewUser = authController.isNewUser;
      final currentLocation = state.matchedLocation;

      if (isLoggedIn && isNewUser) {
        if (currentLocation.contains(AppRoute.login.name)) {
          return '/${AppRoute.nickname.name}';
        }
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        if (currentLocation.contains(AppRoute.login.name)) {
          return '/${AppRoute.home.name}';
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
});

// authController
final authControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthController, AuthState>(
    (ref) => AuthController(userAPI: ref.watch(userAPIProvider)));

class AuthController extends StateNotifier<AuthState> {
  AuthController({required this.userAPI}) : super(AuthState.initial());

  final UserAPI userAPI;

  void login({
    required SocialLoginType providerType,
    required String providerToken,
    required DeviceType deviceType,
    required String deviceUid,
  }) async {
    state = state.copyWith(loginStatus: LoginNetworkStatus.loading);

    try {
      final response = await userAPI.login(
        providerType: providerType,
        providerToken: providerToken,
      );

      state = state.copyWith(
        loginStatus: LoginNetworkStatus.success,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        isNewUser: response.isSignedUp,
      );
    } catch (_) {
      state = state.copyWith(loginStatus: LoginNetworkStatus.error);
      return;
    }
  }
}

enum LoginNetworkStatus { initial, loading, success, error }

class AuthState {
  AuthState({
    required this.loginStatus,
    required this.isLoggedIn,
    required this.isNewUser,
  });

  final LoginNetworkStatus loginStatus;
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  final bool isNewUser;

  factory AuthState.initial() {
    return AuthState(
      loginStatus: LoginNetworkStatus.initial,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      isNewUser: false,
    );
  }

  AuthState copyWith({
    LoginNetworkStatus? loginStatus,
    bool? isLoggedIn,
    bool? isNewUser,
  }) {
    return AuthState(
      loginStatus: loginStatus ?? this.loginStatus,
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn ?? this.isLoggedIn,
      isNewUser: isNewUser ?? this.isNewUser,
    );
  }
}
```

- log

```
I/flutter ( 9257):  Google Login Succeed!
W/e2why.twogather( 9257): Cleared Reference was only reachable from finalizer (only reported once)
[GoRouter] Full paths for routes:
             => /splash
             => /login
             => /nickname
             => /home
           known full paths for route names:
             splash => /splash
             login => /login
             nickname => /nickname
             home => /home
[GoRouter] setting initial location /splash
I/flutter ( 9257):  REDRIRECT
I/flutter ( 9257): isLoggedIn: false
I/flutter ( 9257): isNewUser: false
I/flutter ( 9257): currentLocation: /splash
[GoRouter] Using MaterialApp configuration
D/EGL_emulation( 9257): app_time_stats: avg=1142.15ms min=1142.15ms max=1142.15ms count=1
I/flutter ( 9257):  REQUEST [POST] => http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/user/login
```